# Run codan static code analyser from teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I have codan static code analysis running under Eclipse, I also want to integrate this on our teamcity buildserver but I don't know how. Does some one have some experiance with running codan on a teamcity buildserver?

Or are there other better open source ansi c code analysers which can run on teamcity?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with codan, but the answer is simple: can you run it from the commandline and output results to file?

If so, then TeamCity can easily run it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Codan before, but a quick look seems like it provides more of a plugin framework for static analysis?

[cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) has worked well for me in the past and has a [large set of checks](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page).

It's executed from the command line and can dump issues it finds to a simple XML format.  You can parse that in your build script to produce an HTML report and output [TeamCity build statistics](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildStatistics) (great for graphing progress over time and [failing the build if changes increase issues](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Failure+Conditions)).

See the [cppcheck manual](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf) for examples.  I haven't tried it, but there's also a [cppcheck Eclipse plugin](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/cppcheclipse/) if you want to keep the IDE integration.